# referencedTableSchemaName dropped from addForeignKeyConstraint in liquibase 3.X versions?

Tags: liquibase

Title basically sums it up. Haven't been able to upgrade from 2.0.5 to 3.x because of a foreign key constraint issue.

The parent table lives in a parent schema and there are multiple child schemas with a table that has a FK to the parent schema.table. The child schemes do not have the parent table. Simple enough. The changeset is:

```
<addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames = "AUTHORITY" baseTableName = "GROUP_AUTHORITIES"
                             baseTableSchemaName = "FOO1"
                             constraintName = "FOO1_AUTHORITY_FK" deferrable = "false"
                             initiallyDeferred = "false" onDelete = "NO ACTION" onUpdate = "NO ACTION"
                             referencedColumnNames = "AUTHORITY" referencedTableName = "AUTHORITIES"
                             referencedTableSchemaName = "FOO"
                             referencesUniqueColumn = "true"/>
```

But when the alter statement is created it has the schema for the base table, but not the referenced table as shown.

```
ALTER TABLE FOO1.GROUP_AUTHORITIES ADD CONSTRAINT FOO1_AUTHORITY_FK FOREIGN_KEY (AUTHORITY) REFERENCES AUTHORITIES (AUTHORITY) ON NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

What happened to the referencedTableSchemaName in the alter statement? I'm pretty surprised that noone else has come across this, but I just tried to update again to 3.2 and the same DatabaseException about not able to add foreign key constraint is still happening.

Comment: It should work, what database are you using? Also, does it work better with referencedTableCatalogName ?

Comment: MySQL and Oracle. It doesn't work with referencedTableCatalogName. but you can add the foreign key accross schemas if you uses the constraints tag to create the foreign key with the columns tag.